# How to print properties and key value in array

Tags: php, arrays

I need to access the keys and properties of the arrays. I am bit confuse, I don't know how to handle this easily.

This is the code I run,

```
foreach ($posts as $key=> $value){
    if($value->total_skill!='na'&& $value->total_skill!='0'){
        $selcted = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT `$selection` FROM wp_skilllist WHERE First_name = '$value->First_Name' ");
        var_dump($selcted); 
    }
```

I get following result. I notice that there are lot of arrays inside the arrays. I need to access
propeties and print their results.

As an example

```
FMS_Web_tec_HTML         4

FMS_Web_tec_CSS  3

FMS_Web_tec_XML  4

FMS_Web_tec_JavaScript 2
```

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[257]
      public 'FMS_Web_tec_HTML' => string '4' (length=1)
      public 'FMS_Web_tec_CSS' => string '3' (length=1)
      public 'FMS_Web_tec_XML' => string '4' (length=1)
      public 'FMS_Web_tec_JavaScript' => string '2' (length=1)



array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[258]
      public 'FMS_Web_tec_HTML' => string '3' (length=1)
      public 'FMS_Web_tec_CSS' => string '3' (length=1)
      public 'FMS_Web_tec_XML' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'FMS_Web_tec_JavaScript' => string '2' (length=1)


array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[257]
      public 'FMS_Web_tec_HTML' => string '3' (length=1)
      public 'FMS_Web_tec_CSS' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'FMS_Web_tec_XML' => string '3' (length=1)
      public 'FMS_Web_tec_JavaScript' => string '2' (length=1)
```

Comment: If I am correct it is not two dimentional array.

Comment: if the $posts array contains sub arrays as values, you need to loop through to get their values. try to print_r($posts) and print the array structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think your trying to access the data set in `$selcted`

```
foreach ($selcted as $sel) {
    $vars = get_object_vars($sel);
    foreach ($vars as $key => $var) {
         echo $sel->$key;
    }
}
```

Comment: this can't be done. one reason is content is dynamic, so 'FMS_Web_tec_HTML' can be anything. second is it is collection of arrays

Comment: that case do $sel->$varname

Comment: how do we use $varname? how to set values dynamically?